# How to send fcm notification when app is not running

Tags: android

I have tried many solutions but none of them are worked. I am able receive FCM notification when app is active, but not getting notification when app is background or killed.

Comment: Try passing both the notification and data payload in your FCM notification. Read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a service class extending FirebaseMessagingService and override onMessageReceived method in that class to send notification

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        try {
            message.notification?.let {
                showNotification(
                    it.title ?: "",
                    it.body ?: ""
                )

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

you are now getting the notification info from backend and showing it as a notification by using the function `showNotification`. of course, you must implement the function `showNotification`. it just a simple function for showing notifications in android

**Edit**: this the implementation of the function, add this to your class

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        const val channelId = "Channel"
        const val channelName = "MyChannel"
        const val smallIcon: Int = R.drawable.ic_logo
        const val notificationId = 1
    }

        fun showNotification(myTitle: String, myBody: String) {

        val notificationBuilder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        } else {
            Notification.Builder(applicationContext)
        }

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 -> {
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    channelName,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                )
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
                notificationBuilder
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(myBody)
                    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                    .setContentTitle(myTitle)
            }

            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 -> notificationBuilder
                .setContentText(myBody)
                .setContentTitle(myTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            else -> notificationBuilder
                .setContentText(myBody)
                .setContentTitle(myTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get notification when app is background or killed your json object has to be this like:

{
  "data":{
    "title" : "your_title",
    "body" : "your_body"
  },
  "to": "device_token",
  "priority": "high"
}

You can catch notification onMessageReceived